# DB Link ampersand substitution - ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

Tags: oracle11g, ampersand

I have a installation script in which I am trying to create multiple views based on tables from a remote database. The script will be executed on multiple databases, each with their own remote database. Rather than creating multiple versions of the script, I aim to have remote db link as an input parameter prompted during installation. However when i execute the installation script, the first view fails with ORA-02019 while the remaining views are created successfully.

Sample Test version:

**install.sql**

```
Set serveroutput on

SET VERIFY OFF
Alter Session Set current_schema =  TEST;
SET VERIFY ON

DEFINE DB_LINK = &&db_link

PROMP Install started ...

@./SCRIPTS/views.sql

PROMP Install ended

quit
```

**@./SCRIPTS/views.sql**

```
--View1
Create or replace View tmp_cards as Select nvl((select count(*) from auths@&db_link where  cardid = t.id),0) cnt_auths,t.* From Cards@&db_link t ;

--View2
Create or replace View tmp_Auth as Select * From auths@&db_link;
```

**Installation logs**

```
IMPLUSER@db01 SQL>@install.sql

Session altered.

Enter value for db_link: db02
Install started ...
old   1: Create or replace View tmp_cards as Select nvl((select count(*) from auths@&db_link where  cardid = t.id),0) cnt_auths,t.* From Cards@&db_link t
new   1: Create or replace View tmp_cards as Select nvl((select count(*) from auths@db02 where  cardid = t.id),0) cnt_auths,t.* From Cards@db02 t
Create or replace View tmp_cards as Select nvl((select count(*) from auths@db02 where  cardid = t.id),0) cnt_auths,t.* From Cards@db02 t
                                                                                                                                                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found


old   1: Create or replace View tmp_Auth as Select * From auths@&db_link
new   1: Create or replace View tmp_Auth as Select * From auths@db02

View created.

Install ended
```

if i create the view directly via command window in PL/SQL, the first view is created successfully

```
SQL> Create or replace View tmp_cards as Select nvl((select count(*) from auths@db02 where  I002_NUMBER = t.cardnumber),0) cnt_auths,t.* From Cards@db02 t;
View created

SQL>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can't duplicate in 11.2.0.4 via SQL\*Plus. Is that all of the code involved? Nothing else happens between the failing and working create view statements?

Comment: the only different between the sample version of views.sql and the original file is that i have a couple of comments between the views. I did not think those were relevant. Original post updated to reflect the original script more accurate. .

Comment: Incidentally, for your first view I'd use a left join rather than a subquery, but you'd need to list the cards columns explicitly - which is better than using `*` anyway. Might be worth trying that to see if it behaves the same?

Comment: Yeah, OK, those comments don't matter, but when running this I'd commented what turned out to be the vital part, the `alter session`.This seems to be expected behaviour, see MOS doc ID 793693.1; but that doesn't explain why your subsequent view creations work. See also doc, 2086082.1, bug 20606216, and others.

Comment: replaced the first view with the following:
Create or replace View tmp_cards as
Select Count(a.id) cnt_auths,t.id From cards@&db_link t 
left Outer Join auths@&db_link a on t.id=a.cardid
Group by t.id;
The same error occure.

Comment: Would also be interesting to see if just repeating the first `create` in your script would work around the problem; if it is successful the second time. Is it necessary to connect as some other user and then alter the current schema to TEST, rather than just connecting as TEST?

Comment: Repeating the first view create twice did not resolve the issue. Second view is as before created successfully.. Removing the "alter session" part and connecting directly as TEST does however resolve the issue.. Normally due to internal policy we have to connect as a "deployment user" and change schema during install...

Comment: No, repeating it doesn't help. And it's nothing to do with substitution variables, same thing happens with fixed values, as expected. Playing around with the order things are run makes no difference either. Neither does using `@test.&db_link`. What's really interesting is that the second view works, but running its query standalone as part of the same script fails too. That might be worth a new SR on its own...

Comment: what is worth mentioning is that there is an existing view on db01 named AUTH. AUTH view on DB01 is also based on table AUTH on db02.

Comment: I'm duplicating this with plain tables at the remote end; and the query isn't getting as far as seeing what exists at the remote end. I'm pretty sure your second `create view` should also be failing, based on the 'expected behaviour' notes in MOS, although bug 5358967 maybe suggests it should now work anyway. From MOS there are lots of similar things though, including in 11gR2. I *think* it's failing for any view where the query joins two remote tables (which the second does not); with one works (even though the standalone query doesn't!). I think you need to raise a service request for this.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Atleast I have a feasible workaround for now.